# Migrating EFS across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

Have an `EFS` with two mount targets in US-N.California region and I need to move all the data over to US-Oregon region. Would appreciate any inputs around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [EFS File Sync](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/#filesync) to mirror EFS to another region. Create new endpoints and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim's answer is suggested by AWS, but alternatively you can use any multi-thread NFS client you like, just connect it both src and dest. Single-threaded client can be too slow.